# Adding time Delay in cube teleporting in google cardboard sample code

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

When I look(focusing gazepointer over cube) on the cube teleport (vanishes and then come to new place), I want to add some time delay between its teleport activity.

**1.)Teleport.cs**

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    [RequireComponent(typeof(Collider))]
    public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour {
      private Vector3 startingPosition;

      void Start() {
        startingPosition = transform.localPosition;
        SetGazedAt(false);
      }

      public void SetGazedAt(bool gazedAt) {
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = gazedAt ? Color.green : Color.red;
      }

      public void Reset() {
        transform.localPosition = startingPosition;
      }

      public void ToggleVRMode() {
        Cardboard.SDK.VRModeEnabled = !Cardboard.SDK.VRModeEnabled;
      }

      public void TeleportRandomly() {
        Vector3 direction = Random.onUnitSphere;
        direction.y = Mathf.Clamp(direction.y, 0.5f, 1f);
        float distance = 2 * Random.value + 1.5f;
        transform.localPosition = direction * distance;
      }
    }
```

**2.)Teleportlegacy.cs**

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class TeleportLegacyUI : Teleport {
      private CardboardHead head;

      void Awake() {
        head = Camera.main.GetComponent<StereoController>().Head;
        CardboardOnGUI.IsGUIVisible = true;
        CardboardOnGUI.onGUICallback += this.OnGUI;
      }

      void Update() {
        RaycastHit hit;
        bool isLookedAt = GetComponent<Collider>().Raycast(head.Gaze, out hit, Mathf.Infinity);
        SetGazedAt(isLookedAt);
        if (Cardboard.SDK.Triggered && isLookedAt) {
                print("gazed");
                ///maaaaibbbbbbbnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
               TeleportRandomly();
               //Update2();
        }
      }

      void OnGUI() {
        if (!CardboardOnGUI.OKToDraw(this)) {
          return;
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(50, 50, 200, 50), "Reset")) {
          Reset();
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(50, 110, 200, 50), "Recenter")) {
          Cardboard.SDK.Recenter();
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(50, 170, 200, 50), "VR Mode")) {
          ToggleVRMode();
        }
      }

      void OnDestroy() {
        CardboardOnGUI.onGUICallback -= this.OnGUI;
      }
    }
```

How should I make the time delay between the teleport activity of cube?

Comment: When you need the time delay, use the Invoke() method to access the/a Teleport function instead of teleporting it directly

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a coroutine, you might need to add a flag or something to avoid it getting double triggered (you could reset it at the end of the coroutine)

```
public IEnumerator TeleportCoroutine()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.5f);
    Vector3 direction = Random.onUnitSphere;
    direction.y = Mathf.Clamp(direction.y, 0.5f, 1f);
    float distance = 2 * Random.value + 1.5f;
    transform.localPosition = direction * distance;
 }

  public void TeleportRandomly() {
    StartCoroutine(TeleportCoroutine());
  }
```

Edit: If you'd like the object to warp after being gazed at for a certain amount of time, try:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TeleportLegacyUI : Teleport {

private CardboardHead head;
private float gazeTotalTime = 0;

void Awake() 
{
    head = Camera.main.GetComponent<StereoController>().Head;
    CardboardOnGUI.IsGUIVisible = true;
    CardboardOnGUI.onGUICallback += this.OnGUI;
}

void Update() {
    RaycastHit hit;
    bool isLookedAt = GetComponent<Collider>().Raycast(head.Gaze, out hit, Mathf.Infinity);
    SetGazedAt(isLookedAt);

    if(isLookedAt)
        gazeTotalTime += Time.deltaTime;
    else
        gazeTotalTime = 0;

    if(gazeTotalTime > 1.0f)
        TeleportRandomly();
}

void OnGUI() {
    if (!CardboardOnGUI.OKToDraw(this)) {
        return;
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(50, 50, 200, 50), "Reset")) {
        Reset();
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(50, 110, 200, 50), "Recenter")) {
        Cardboard.SDK.Recenter();
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(50, 170, 200, 50), "VR Mode")) {
        ToggleVRMode();
    }
}

void OnDestroy() {
    CardboardOnGUI.onGUICallback -= this.OnGUI;
}
}
```

Comment: i want to make the teleport action with delay on just gaze(taking the gazepointer) over the cube not on clicking

Comment: What should i do if i want to switch to another scene on looking onto cube for a couple of seconds

Comment: Change the 1.0f in "if(gazeTotalTime > 1.0f)" to however many seconds you'd like to have the user gaze at the target before warping.

Comment: Its almost there but the sound effect (var Audio= gameObject.GetComponent(AudioSource);) i have put it repeating continuously till the next scene switch.....